# Improved power recursive function

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a recursive function to elevate one number to the power of another where x^n=(x^(n/2)^2 if n is even or x^n=x*(x^(n-1)) if n is odd.

I've been thinking about it for quite a while and tried a few things
but honestly I don't know how to approach the problem, especially if n is odd. I've written a bit of code in case n is even but I don't even know if it would make sense to post it as the logic behind it is pretty broken itself.

Any help appreciated!

```
int power(int x, int n){
  int result = 1;

  if(n % 2 == 0){
    n /= 2;
    for(; n > 0; n--){
      result *= x;
    }
    power(result, 2);
  }

  return result;

}
```

2nd try, no for loops:

```
int power(int x, int n){
  int result = 1;

  if(n % 2 == 0){
    result *= x;
    power(x, n / 2);
  }

  return result;

}
```

Comment: Writing a recursive function to calculate an arbitrary exponent isn't challenging.  We're not here to write code for you; why not post your best try and we can take it from there.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer just updated with my code. I wasn't expecting anyone to write anything for me, just a little tip on the reasoning behind it ahah anyways I know my code is broken but I can't find any better solution

Comment: You call your function recursively to evaluate something; you ignore the value that's returned.  This seems likely to give problems.  I'm not clear why you want a recursive function — the iterative code is simple and sufficient.

Comment: You have no base case in your recursion, so you recurse infinitely.

Comment: The code you've written doesn't match the algorithm you've described. What you've described doesn't need any loops, just recursive calls and multiplication. Also, you don't have a base case for `n == 2`; you should define a special case for that, like `x * x`.

Comment: Actually, the base cases should be `n == 0` and `n == 1`.

Comment: @Barmar The algorithm given in the question, when `n == 2`, gives a result of x^1^2, or `power(power(x, 1), 2)`, which isn't useful. Either you need a separate base case for `n == 2`, or you need to implement the `^2` part differently.

Comment: @DanielH so I got rid of the for loop but the function prints out just the base. Like 3^8 = 3, 4^12 = 4, etc. Is it because I'm declaring result = 1 at the beginning so every time the function gets called recursively the value of result gets resetted to 1?

Comment: At no point in your explanation of how to handle the even cases do you actually multiply by `x`, so why are you doing that in the code? You also still have the problem @JonathanLeffler mentioned of not using the result of the recursive call. You should probably have `result = power(...)` as part of your code, to actually use the result of the recursive call.

Comment: @DanielH well I mean how's the function gonna know that power means multiply the base by itself n amounts of time if I never multiply for the base?

Comment: Basically, the way to write a recursive function is to figure out some way to define a "smaller" problem. In this case, that's where you have a smaller `n`. So write the cases which can't be reduced, which as Barmar says are  0 and 1. Then, write the rest of the function assuming that it somehow already works for any smaller `n`. Since `n/2` is always less than `n` (if `n` is positive), you can just use that and assume it works. The multiplication happens either with odd `n` where you multiply by `x` directly, or with even `n` when you square the result of the smaller calculation.

Comment: You should always start with the base cases. So your function have a form something like be `int power(int x, int n) { if (n == 0) { return 1; } if (n % 2 == 0) { /* handle even */ } else { /* handle odd */ } }` (I realized that the `n == 1` case isn't actually a base case the way you defined the recursion; it can recurse to `n == 0` without an issue.)

Comment: @DanielH I feel very dumb right now but I still don't get it.....

Comment: If you expand out the algorithm given in your question for 3^8, since 8 is even,you calculate (3^4) squared (I'm handling the "squared" introduced in your rule for even numbers differently than raising something to the 2, for reasons I'll explain in the next comment). Since 4 is also even, this is calculated as ((3^2) squared) squared. Since 2 is also even, this becomes (((3^1) squared) squared) squared. Since 1 is odd, this becomes (((3 * (3^0)) squared) squared) squared. Once you get to 3^0 it doesn't make sense to keep trying for smaller powers, so you just say anything to the zero is 1.

Comment: You now have (((3 * 1) squared) squared) squared. Since you're writing `power`, not `times`, you can just let the compiler do the multiplication and get ((3 squared) squared) squared. You need to do the "squared" part yourself outside the recursive function or you end up defining 3^2 as (3^1)^2, which would then evaluate to 3^2 again and never finish computing. The answer to "how's the function gonna know that power means multiply the base by itself n times" is "It evaluates all those 'squared's and the '3*' we had when evaluating 3^1."

Comment: @DanielH Those comments should really be an answer.

Comment: @Barmar They don't get all the way to an answer, which is why I didn't make them one, but you're right. I'll edit them into one shortly.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a literal translation of "x^n=(x^(n/2)^2 if n is even or x^n=x*(x^(n-1)) if n is odd" using recursion:

```
int power(int x, int n){
    int temp;

    if(n % 2 == 0){
        // n is even
        temp = power(x, n / 2);
        return temp * temp;
    } else {
        // n is odd
        return x * power(x, n - 1);
    }
}
```

Note that this code is deliberately wrong (will probably recurse "forever" and cause a stack overflow) because the original description didn't include special handling for the `n = 0` case.

For a more correct/less literal version:

```
int power(int x, int n){
    int temp;

    if(n % 2 == 0){
        // n is even
        if(n == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        temp = power(x, n / 2);
        return temp * temp;
    } else {
        // n is odd
        return x * power(x, n - 1);
    }
}
```

Of course this is relatively awful (for readability/maintainability and performance) because the requirements are awful. A version that ignores the requirements (and isn't recursive) would be:

```
int power(int x, int n){
    int result = 1;

    while(n > 0) {
          if( (n & 1) != 0) {
              result *= x;
          }
          n >>= 1;
          x *= x;
    }
    return result;
}
```

**OFF-TOPIC ADDENDUM**

For calculating powers, if you convert the exponent into binary you can use each binary digit as a flag to determine whether or not to multiply the result with the "squared each iteration" temporary value. For example, `x**5` is the same as `(x**4) * (x**1)` because `5 == 101b`.

**This is important/useful when you need to handle fractional exponents.** For example, `x**5.5` is the same as `(x**4) * (x**1) * (x**0.5)` because `5.5 == 101.1b`.

In other words, starting from the exponent's decimal point and going towards the most significant bit through the integer part of the exponent you can `if(next bit of exponent was set) { result *= temp}; temp *= temp;`; and starting from the exponents decimal point and going towards the least significant bit through the fractional portion of the exponent you can `if(next bit of exponent was set) { result *= temp}; temp = sqrt(temp);`.

When I first wrote this answer the last example code was written using the "convert exponent to binary digits" method I've described here, with no regard to the "x^n=(x^(n/2)^2 if n is even or x^n=x*(x^(n-1)) if n is odd" in the original question. It wasn't until later that I realised that the approach in the original question ends up being equivalent code from a different perspective.

Comment: The requirements for recursive functions are always awful; there are legitimate uses for recursion but they aren't simple as teaching aids. You shouldn't calculate this or factorial using recursion (in a C-like language; if you're using a functional language things are different), and you shouldn't even use a loop for Fibonacci. However, I would like to point out that for modern compilers, `>>= 1` is exactly equivalent to `/= 2`, and the latter is generally more readable. Similarly for `n & 1` and `n % 2`, I'd go with the readable option and hope the compiler isn't stupid.

Comment: @DanielH: For the last version, I see it as converting `n` to binary where shifts and AND are more natural for extracting bits. There's logical reasons for this, but it's hard to fit an explanation into a comment due to the "number of characters" limit - will "cheat" and add an off-topic section to my answer (in the hope that people don't mind too much that I probably shouldn't given that it should be educational for those interested).

Comment: Yeah, thinking of it that way it makes complete sense to do it that way. I think there should be an off topic section to explain why; I only understand your comment because I've seen it that way before and just didn't get it from the code.

Comment: The last `power(int x, int n)` has troubles when 1) `result` is in `int` range, yet `x *= x` overflows (UB).   2) rare non-2's complement platforms.  3) `n < 0`.  The recursive version does not  have problems #1, #2 and fewer #3 problems.  Certainly better defined code should we move to `unsigned n`.

Comment: @chux: I"m just using the same signature as the OP (`int power(int, int)`) - the nature of `pow()` means that it's likely to overflow with relatively small inputs regardless of what you do (unless you use floating point or big numbers - e.g. `double power(int, int)`). It's trivial to add support for negative exponents (e.g. `if(n < 0) return 1/power(x, -n);`) but that isn't particularly useful if you're using any integer type. Negative bases should work for all versions.

Comment: Example: with 32-bit `int`, `int_OP(7,11)` does not OF `int` math yet `int_Breden(7,11)` does OF `x *= x`. Thus the _improved_ code has unexpected UB when the "relatively awful"  does not.  IMO, not a good trade.  Certainly a non-recursive approach, without new UB is possible, yet this is not it..

Comment: @chux: Who cares? The last example is a better (easier to explain, easier to learn, easier to remember) way to teach the implementation; and is cleaner, faster and extremely likely to give identical results in all possible cases (because if there is a "UB in theory" it's extremely likely that it'll just be an undefined value that won't be used); and it's completely obvious that nobody here cares about the max. ranges or overflow (based on the fact that `int` is being used and not `double`).

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at how you're supposed to evaluate this to see if we can understand it better, before getting into the code. I'll use `monospace` for the math, not C code, to distinguish it more easily:

First, for reasons I'll get to later, I'll need to change your rule for even numbers a bit. Instead of doing `(x^(n/2))^2`, I'm going to write out `squared`; you need to handle this part differently than the other parts. Other than that, every instance of `^` in your question means "we need to calculate this power using the same algorithm".

This means that your algorithm is:

- If `n` is even, then `x^n = (x^(n/2)) squared`.
- If `n` is odd, then `x^n = x*(x^(n-1))`.

Let's look at how this plays out with a simple example of `3^5`. If you expand this out, since `5` is odd, you end up with `3 * (3^4)`. You still don't know what `3^4` is, so you need to expand it out again using the same algorithm. Since `4` is even, this is calculated as `(3^2) squared`, so the full value of `3^5` is `3 * ((3^2) squared)`. Again, we evaluate `^` using the same algorithm; since `2` is also even, this becomes `3 * ((3^1 squared) squared)`. This also has a `^`; so we do the same thing: use the algorithm above. Since `1` is odd, this becomes `3 * (((3 * 3^0) squared) squared)`.

Now, `0` is even, but once you get to `3^0` it doesn't make sense to keep trying for smaller powers. Since `0/2` is `0`, you'd be back where you started, trying to evaluate `3^0` again. Therefore, `0` needs to be a handled as a special case. This adds a third rule to the algorithm:

- If `n` is `0`, then `x^n = 1`.

In code, you need to check this before you check the "If `n` is even" rule, because `0` is even and we want to run this check first. Every recursive algorithm has at least one special case like this, and sometimes more; the term for them is *base case*.¹

Now that we have a rule for handling `x^0`, we can continue finding `3^5`. Our last step was `3 * (((3 * 3^0) squared) squared)`. Using our `x^0` rule, this becomes `3 * (((3 * 1) squared) squared)`. Since we no longer have `^` in this expression, we have finished recursing. Now we just need to calculate the result: `3 * ((3 squared) squared)`. You still need to solve `squared` without using this `^` operation, but since the exponent is fixed you can just write it as a multiplication. If you do that, you get `3 * (9 squared)`, then `3 * 81`, then `243`, which is our final answer.

In the comments, you asked "how's the function gonna know that power means multiply the base by itself n times". The answer to that is "We calculated `3*1`, and squared the result a couple times, and then multiplied by 3 again. That's where all the multiplications are: some are outright multiplications by `3`, and the squarings double the effective number of multiplications performed."

¹ The standard examples of recursion are factorial (`n! = n * (n-1)!` and Fibonacci numbers (`F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n - 2)`). For factorial the base case is `0! = 1`, and for Fibonacci numbers there are two base cases, `F(0) = 0` and `F(1) = 1`.

---

A few loose ends:

- The problem with using this same power function for squaring in the even case is that it would lead to an infinite loop at `3^2`. If we evaluated that without changing the rule for even numbers, we'd get `(3^1)^2`. As we saw, `3^1` is `3`, so we'd be back to `3^2`. This tells us that `3^2` does equal `3^2`, which is true, but useless. Another option would be to make `n = 2` another base case after `n = 0`, but this way is somewhat cleaner.
- The final algorithm, after adding the base case and using `squared` instead of `^2` for even numbers, is:

  - If `n` is `0`, then `x^n = 1`.
  - Otherwise, if `n` is even, then `x^n = (x^(n/2)) squared`.
  - Otherwise `n` is odd, so `x^n = x*(x^(n-1))`.
- To put this into code, see [Brendan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53643270/27302). Since it's useful to look at the call stack, here's what happens in the second version of the code in that answer, which is very close to what I describe:

  - `power(3, 5)` executes `return 3 * power(3, 4);`.
  - `power(3, 4)` executes `temp = power(3, 2);`.
  - `power(3, 2)` executes `temp = power(3, 1);`.
  - `power(3, 1)` executes `return 3 * power(3, 0);`.
  - `power(3, 0)` return `1` to `power(3, 1)`.
  - `power(3, 1)` evaluates `3 * 1` and returns `3` to `power(3, 2)`.
  - `power(3, 2)` executes `return temp * temp`, evaluating `3 * 3`, and returns `9` to `power(3, 4)`.
  - `power(3, 4)` executes `return temp * temp`, evaluating `9 * 9`, and returns `81` to `power(3, 5)`.
  - `power(3, 5)` evaluates `3 * 81` and returns `243`.
- In programming, especially around C-like languages, I often see `**` used for exponentiation instead of `^`, because `^` means something else (bitwise xor).

Comment: Note: `x^n = x*(x^(n-1))` makes sense when `n>=0`.  IMO, rather than try and fix code to cope with `n < 0`, better to use `unsigned n`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int power(int n1, int n2);

int main()
{
    int base, powerRaised, result;

    printf("Enter base number: ");
    scanf("%d",&base);

    printf("Enter power number(positive integer): ");
    scanf("%d",&powerRaised);

    result = power(base, powerRaised);

    printf("%d^%d = %d", base, powerRaised, result);
    return 0;
}

int power(int base, int powerRaised)
{
    if (powerRaised != 0)
        return (base*power(base, powerRaised-1));
    else
        return 1;
}
```

Comment: This still uses the wrong algorithm, and you should explain what you're doing and why instead of just providing code, but if you fix that you should do so by editing instead of just posting a new answer.